# Oracle Application Express Listener PDF Report

Tags: oracle, reporting, listener, oracle-apex

We need our reports to be available in PDF format on our Oracle 11g, APEX:4.2.6

Followed [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r42/PDF_Printing_oll/PDF_Printing_oll.html) tutorial and selected "Oracle APEX Listener".

But the generated PDF report is empty.

We are using EPG.

Do we have to install/configure anything else other than the mentioned tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer from an Oracle Employee on Oracle Community:

"The problem is when the default page size is set to A4, which translates into points with decimals when rendering the PDF. Please, change the Units to Points, and round up your page width and height."

Reference:

https://community.oracle.com/message/1793888

Comment: It does now create the PDF report, and file size is greater than 1 K, But cannot open the file. Msg is either file corrupt or in-correct format.